# Is it possible to automatically apply a tag in Gmail and then hiding part of the subject?

Tags: gmail, gmail-filters, gmail-labels, inbox-by-gmail

I would like to automatically apply a label to every mail containing `[Something]` in the subject and then hiding that part when the mail are showed in the Inbox.

For example i receive an email with the following subject:

> [Something] This is an example

It should apply a label (for example `SMTH`) and then show it in the inbox as follow:

> `SMTH` This is an example

Is it possible to do such a thing in Gmail?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

GMAIL doesn't include a built-in feature to hide, not change, a part of the email subject. You could try to use a [userscript](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Userscript).

To help using user scripts you could use web-browser addons like [Greasemonkey](https://addons.mozilla.org/es/firefox/addon/greasemonkey/) for Firefox of [Tampermonkey](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/tampermonkey/dhdgffkkebhmkfjojejmpbldmpobfkfo?hl=es) for Google Chrome, among other alternatives.

Another approach is to change the email subject. For this you could use [Google Apps Script](https://www.google.com/script/start/), the [GMail API](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/) or a third-party tool.

To ask for a software recommendation consider https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com